# Generate random variates and cdf from Tweedie distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, random-generation, cumulative-distribution-function, tweedie-distribution

I have to generate some random variates from a Tweedie distribution with the following parameters:

$p = 1$
$\mu = \bar{\mu}$
$\phi = \bar{\phi}$

I do not have direct access to a function that is able to calculates random variates from the Tweedie distribution, however, since $p =1$, I can use the Poisson distribution to generate random variates.
Let's assume that $\mathcal{R_p}(\lambda)$ it is a function, that given the input value $\lambda$ (the mean of the Poisson distribution) gives me back a random variate from a Poisson distribution.
I can then define the function $\mathcal{R_T}(\mu, \phi) = \phi * \mathcal{R_p}(\lambda = \mu/\phi)$ and I will get random variates from the corresponding Tweedie distribution. Is this correct?
Moreover, If I need the cumulative distribution function of a Tweedie distribution, I can also compute the value based on the corresponding Poisson distribution.
Let's assume that  $\mathcal{F_p}(y, \lambda)$ gives the cdf of a Poisson distribution in $y$. The corresponding cdf of a Tweedie distribution can be calculated as:
$\mathcal{F_T}(x, \mu, \phi)$ = $\mathcal{R_p}(y = x/\phi, \lambda=\mu/\phi)$, Is this correct or is should be $\mathcal{F_T}(x, \mu, \phi)$ = $\mathcal{R_p}(y = x, \lambda=\mu/\phi)$? Since we are multiplying the random variates from the Poisson distribution by $\phi$, shall we divide it by $\phi$ again when calculating the cdf?

Comment: This may be not relevant but there are R functions for generating Tweedie distributions like [rtweedie](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.8-31/topics/rTweedie). And [rtweedie](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tweedie/tweedie.pdf).